# Повторяющиеся значения при записи

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3

Всем привет)
Есть такая проблема, пишу данные ,в цикле раз в 0,1 сек, в базу. Вот код

```
import sqlite3
import time
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
import pandas as pd



mt5.initialize()
mt5.copy_rates_from_pos('EURUSD', mt5.TIMEFRAME_M1, 0, 1)

def get_ohlc(ativo, timeframe, n=55):
    ativo = mt5.copy_rates_from_pos(ativo, timeframe, 0, n)
    ativo = pd.DataFrame(ativo)
    ativo['time']=pd.to_datetime(ativo['time'], unit='s')
    ativo.set_index('time', inplace=True)
    return ativo

get_ohlc('EURUSD', mt5.TIMEFRAME_M1)
info = mt5.symbol_info_tick('EURUSD')
#print(info)


#Создает новый файл , если он есть то просто подключается
base = sqlite3.connect('new_base.db')
#Класс для создания, чтения, изменения таблиц


#Создание таблицы
base.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data_eurusd(time PRIMARY KEY, last, bid, ask, value, flag, real_volume)")




#Повтор кода для исполнения
tempo = time.time() + 1000000000000
while time.time() < tempo:
    tick = mt5.symbol_info_tick('EURUSD')
    vrema = tick.time_msc
    last = tick.last
    bid = tick.bid
    ask = tick.ask
    value = tick.volume
    flag = tick.flags
    value_real = tick.volume_real
    cur = base.cursor()
    # Заполнение значением в таблицу. Кол-во ?? соответствует кол-ву столбцов
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO data_eurusd VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (vrema, last, bid, ask, value, flag, value_real))# Значения
    base.commit()
   #print(f"TIME_ms:{tick.time_msc}, EURUSD:{tick.last}, цена BID:{tick.bid}, цена ASK:{tick.ask}, объем:{tick.volume}, FLAG:{tick.flags}, REAL:{tick.volume_real} ", end='\n')
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Проблема заключается в том, что в таблице столбец time является уникальным для него значений, однако значения повторяются. Есть ли метод какой для того , чтобы только уникальные значения записывались.?? ну или есть ли метод, который гуляет по строкам и сравниевает их, и если они равны, то удаляет последнюю?

[image: база_значения]

Comment: Нужно научиться проверять, существует ли уже такая запись. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45569344/how-to-tell-if-a-value-exists-in-a-sqlite3-database-python - что-то похожее.

Comment: у Вас поле time в секундах, Вы пишите данные раз в 0,1 секунду) Ну конечно оно будет не уникальным, тут даже в код вникать не надо. Либо делайте промежутки в секунду, либо в тайм добавьте милисекунды.

Comment: добавлял... ничего не менялось... данные приходящие , и если они не обновились в течении 2х минут, то за 2 минуты будут приходить одни и теже данные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> есть ли метод, который гуляет по строкам и сравнивает их, и если они
> равны, то удаляет последнюю?

Это совершенно лишнее. Гораздо проще и эффективней завести переменную (к примеру) *last_write_time* и, перед тем, как выполнять оператор

```
cur.execute(..)
```

просто проверять на совпадение текущее время и *last_write_time*. Если они совпадают - не выполнять вставку записи в таблицу.

> не могу понять как прописать

Перед циклом добавления данных поставить

```
last_write_time = 0
```

А сам цикл добавления строк в таблицу немного поменять. Я пишу только изменяемый кусок теккста:

```
if vrema != last_write_time:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO data_eurusd VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (vrema, last, bid, ask, value, flag, value_real))
    last_write_time = vrema
```

Comment: я новичек в этотм....не могу понять как прописать